# Swift 4 Retrieving Data From Firebase Database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

```
func retPost2(){
runNBPOST()
////////////////////////////////////1


var pic = [String]()
var p = Post(userId: "", postId: "", postType: "", description: "", Region: "", City: "", District: "", Street: "", Area: 0, View: "", TotalPrice: 0, Pictures: pic, StreetWidth: 0, PropertyType: "")






////// for to retrive all post




print(retNBPOST())
runNBPOST()
let nbpost = retNBPOST()


for i in 1..<nbpost{


    postiiD = "Post(\(i))"


    self._REF_BASE.child("Post").child(postiiD).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let UserID2 = value?["UserID"] as? String ?? ""
        p.userId = UserID2
    })





    self._REF_BASE.child("Post").child("\("Post(\(i))")/Adress").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let Region = value?["Region"] as? String ?? ""
        p.Region = Region
        let City = value?["City"] as? String ?? ""
        p.City = City
        print(p.City)
        let District = value?["District"] as? String ?? ""
        p.District = District
        let Street = value?["Street"] as? String ?? ""
        p.Street = Street
        let AdditionalNumber = value?["AdditionalNumber"] as? String ?? ""
        p.AdditionalNumber = AdditionalNumber
        let PostalCode = value?["PostalCode"] as? String ?? ""
        p.PostalCode = PostalCode
        let BuldingNo = value?["BuldingNo"] as? String ?? ""
        p.BuldingNo = BuldingNo


    })

    self._REF_BASE.child("Post").child("\(postiiD)/PostInfo").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let postType = value?["PostType"] as? String ?? ""
        p.postType = postType
        print(p.postType)
        let DateOfpost = value?["DateOfpost"] as? String ?? ""
        p.dateOfpost = DateOfpost
        let EndDateOfPost = value?["EndDateOfPost"] as? String ?? ""
        p.endDateOfPost = EndDateOfPost
        let NbOfShare = value?["NbOfShare"] as? String ?? ""
        p.nbOfShare = Int(NbOfShare)!
        let NbOfViews = value?["NbOfViews"] as? String ?? ""
        p.nbOfViews = Int(NbOfViews)!
        let LastUpdate = value?["LastUpdate"] as? String ?? ""
        p.lastUpdate = LastUpdate
        let Description = value?["Description"] as? String ?? ""
        p.description = Description
        let Publisher = value?["Publisher"] as? String ?? ""
        p.publisher = Publisher
        let ContactTime = value?["ContactTime"] as? String ?? ""
        p.contactTime = ContactTime
        let Payment = value?["Payment"] as? String ?? ""
        p.payment = Payment
        let TotalPrice = value?["TotalPrice"] as? String ?? ""
        p.TotalPrice = Double(TotalPrice)!
        let NearBy = value?["NearBy"] as? String ?? ""
        p.NearBy = NearBy
        let StreetWidth = value?["StreetWidth"] as? String ?? ""
        p.StreetWidth = Double(StreetWidth)!
        //  let Discount = value?["Discount"] as? String ?? ""
        // p.Discount =


    })



    self._REF_BASE.child("Post").child("\(postiiD)/Property").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let Area = value?["Area"] as? String ?? ""
        p.Area = Double(Area)!
        print(p.Area)
        let View = value?["View"] as? String ?? ""
        p.View = View
        let FamilyOrSingle = value?["FamilyOrSingle"] as? String ?? ""
        p.FamilyOrSingle = FamilyOrSingle
        let Level = value?["Level"] as? String ?? ""
        p.Level = Int(Level)!
        let HouseAge = value?["HouseAge"] as? String ?? ""
        p.HouseAge = Int(HouseAge)!
        let LandType = value?["LandType"] as? String ?? ""
        p.LandType = LandType
        let MeterPrice = value?["MeterPrice"] as? String ?? ""
        p.MeterPrice = Double(MeterPrice)!
        let NbRoom = value?["NbRoom"] as? String ?? ""
        p.NbRoom = Int(NbRoom)!

        let NbGuestroom = value?["NbGuestroom"] as? String ?? ""
        p.NbGuestroom = Int(NbGuestroom)!
        let NbBathroom = value?["NbBathroom"] as? String ?? ""
        p.NbBathroom = Int(NbBathroom)!
        let NbBedroom = value?["NbBedroom"] as? String ?? ""
        p.NbBedroom = Int(NbBedroom)!
        let NbLivingroom = value?["NbLivingroom"] as? String ?? ""
        p.NbLivingroom = Int(NbLivingroom)!
        let NbKitchen = value?["NbKitchen"] as? String ?? ""
        p.NbKitchen = Int(NbKitchen)!
        let PropertyType = value?["PropertyType"] as? String ?? ""
        p.PropertyType = PropertyType
        let NbApartment = value?["NbApartment"] as? String ?? ""
        p.NbApartment = Int(NbApartment)!


    })


    // complet
    self._REF_BASE.child("Post").child("\(postiiD)/Amenities").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let LiftAvailability = value?["LiftAvailability"] as? String ?? ""
        let KitchenAvailability = value?["KitchenAvailability"] as? String ?? ""
        let FurnitureAvailability = value?["FurnitureAvailability"] as? String ?? ""
        let CarageAvailability = value?["CarageAvailability"] as? String ?? ""
        let SwimmingPoolAvailability = value?["SwimmingPoolAvailability"] as? String ?? ""
        let ParkingAvailability = value?["ParkingAvailability"] as? String
        let FiberOpticAvailability = value?["FiberOpticAvailability"] as? String
        let FireplaceAvailability = value?["FireplaceAvailability"] as? String
        let DiningroomAvailability = value?["DiningroomAvailability"] as? String
        let LaundryAvailability = value?["LaundryAvailability"] as? String
        let CentralAirAvailability = value?["CentralAirAvailability"] as? String
        let BalconyAvailability = value?["BalconyAvailability"] as? String
        let MaidRoomAvailability = value?["MaidRoomAvailability"] as? String
        let DriverRoomAvailability = value?["DriverRoomAvailability"] as? String
        let InternalStairAvailability = value?["InternalStairAvailability"] as? String
        let BasementAvailability = value?["BasementAvailability"] as? String
    })


    arrpost.append(p)


}


}


func updateHomeView(post : Post){

    totalPriceLb.text = "\(String(post.TotalPrice)) SR"
    areaLb.text = String(post.Area)
    AddressLb.text = "\(post.City) \(post.District) \(post.Street)"
    imageName.image = UIImage(named: "HomePic.jpg")

    if post.PropertyType == "Home" {
        bathLb.text = String(post.NbBathroom)
        BedLb.text = String(post.NbBedroom)
        imageName.image = UIImage(named: "HomePic.jpg")
    }else if post.PropertyType == "Apartment" {
        bathLb.text = String(post.NbBathroom)
        BedLb.text = String(post.NbBedroom)
        imageName.image = UIImage(named: "ApartPic.jpg")
    }else if post.PropertyType == "Land"{
        bathLb.isHidden = true
        BedLb.isHidden = true
        imageName.image = UIImage(named: "LandPic.jpg")
    }




}





func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {



    DataService.instance.retPost2()
  // tableView.reloadData()


  return DataService.instance.arrpost.count

}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)



}

func tableView
    (_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell") as! homecell

    let post = DataService.instance.arrpost[indexPath.row]
 //  let post = DataServiceTemp.instance.getPosts()[indexPath.row]
    cell.updateHomeView(post: post)

  // tableView.reloadData()

    return cell


}
```

I have a problem in my IOS App. I'm Using Firebase for saving & Retrieving data. All connections are good and the data is retrieved fine or sometimes incomplete.
And My Problem is when I run the app the views, labels, Pictures, etc are shown Empty at first when this components should show the data retrieved from firebase. I don't know what's the problem. Is it time or anything else? So the main problem is the components are shown empty before retrieving the data completely. I want to force the app to not show empty at first but showing the components with data.

[image: my Firebase Database]

I already use all method from google
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write

Comment: "So the main problem is the components are shown empty before retrieving the data completely."  Your main problem is that you don't show a single line of code.  Nobody knows how you are doing it in their wildest dream.

Comment: The OP is showing the UI before Firebase has a chance to retrieve the data. The app 'flow' should let he user know the data is being retrieved then the UI updated within the closure following the firebase call. You may also be trying to retreive too much data at one time and/or how the data is being processed. But as @ElTomato states, we really can't suggest more because there's no code. Please review the following [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Don't use Images](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 0):

Make hover `UIView` above the mainVC with a `UIActivityIndicator` until response comes from Firebase remove it